# imbalance in sample size at multilevel longitudinal data

Tags: sample-size, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, skewness, nested-data

I have longitudinal data (BMI level) measured at 3 time points and subjects are students nested to schools.  The sample size in school level differs considerably (n=85 % in school 1, n=10 % in school 2, and n=5% in school 3. I fitted random intercept and slope model taking into account nesting structure. I am not sure if the results would be valid because of highly skewed sample size.  I was wondering if there is a technique for balancing sample size so that schools are comparable.

Comment: Rather than being worried about the sample size I'd be more worried about the reason for why schools are so different. In the worst case this hints towards a selection problem.

Comment: @ Andy, originally, the plan was to get similar size at each shool but at data collection point some unavoidable issues arose that resulted skewed sample size.